# Can a for loop be used in a JOptionPane.showMessageDialog?

Tags: joptionpane

So I'm new here, and this is my first question...Is there a proper syntax for using the for loop in JOptionPane.showMessageDialog?

This is my current code and I know that it doesn't work. My code is for showing the factors of a certain integer and I want to know how can I show that in a JOptionPane.

```
String c = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null
,for(d=1;d<=c;d++){
   if(c%d==0){
     d+" "
   }
 }  
,"The factors of "+c+" are: "
,JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: You can't use the JOptionPane.showMessageDialog like this but you can do you own JDialog (extend it) with the JTextField (for input) and JLabel (for result) and an actionListener on the JTextField (enter) to display the result...

Comment: @PetterFriberg thanks for the immediate answer, also if possible could you provide a sample code? I forgot to mention it at the start but I'm still a beginner at java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Petter Friberg for giving an answer, I found a solution to my problem thanks to you, although I didn't use all of your suggestions . So here's my code...

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class TestNo3{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      JTextArea factorsArea = new JTextArea();
      JTextField inputInt1 = new JTextField(5);
      JPanel factorsPanel = new JPanel();
        factorsPanel.add(new JLabel("Enter an integer: "));
        factorsPanel.add(inputInt1);

     int int1 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, factorsPanel
        ,"Show the factors of a number."
        ,JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
          if(int1==JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
            String inputIntS = inputInt1.getText();
            int inputIntI = Integer.parseInt(inputIntS);

            for(int numB=1;numB<=inputIntI;numB++){
              if(inputIntI%numB==0){
                String outputS = String.format("%5d", numB); 
                factorsArea.append(outputS);        
              }
            }

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, factorsArea
                ,"The factors of "+inputIntI+" are: "
                ,JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);      
          }
    }
}
```